# Добавление каждого следующего сообщение в БД

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Подскажите как сделать так, что бы программа считывала каждое следующее сообщение и добавляла его в БД

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def addStart(message):
    a = message.text
    a = a.split(', ')
    name, total, price = a
    main.addInStart(name, int(total), float(price))

def addInStart(name: str, total: int, price: float):
    pos = (name, total, price)

    cur.execute('SELECT name FROM start WHERE name = ?', (name, ))
    if cur.fetchone() is None:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO start VALUES (?, ?, ?)', pos)
        main_db.commit()
    else: 
        print('Такая запись уже есть!')
```

В эту функцию клиент переходит по кнопке и может ввести только одну позицию. Если это сделать невозможно, то как сделать так что бы пользователь мог несколько позиций за раз добавить?